# Launch nautilus with option for path

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys

I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> set to launch `gksu nautilus`.  This set me thinking: can I have a prompt that comes up that asks me for a path to open?  Ideally, I'd be able to hit a key combo, type `/usr/share/applications`, and have Nautilus open up without having to use the GUI to get there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **zenity** to create a text box dialog from the terminal, which you can use to specify a path.

Install `zenity` from a terminal if it's not already installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install zenity
```

Now you can create interesting dialog boxes from the terminal:

```
$ zenity --entry --text='Enter nautilus path:'
```

[image]

Now that you can graphically enter a path, how do you hand this off to nautilus?  How about some **bash** magic!

```
$ nautilus $(zenity --entry --text='Enter nautilus path:')
```

You've successfully provided your path to nautilus as an argument.  Now just bind this command to the shortcut of your choice!